# Exibir data format pt-br dd/mm/aaaa

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde!
Estou utilizando o plugin [air-datepicker](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/) para datas.

Quando eu clico no campo, eu vejo o formato pt-br dd/mm/aaaa.

Agora, portanto, eu quero que ao abrir a janela modal, esta data seja exibida no mesmo formato dd/mm/aaaa, já que esta sendo exibida no formato yyyy-mm-dd.

Lembrando que estou utilizando ajax.

Abaixo Ajax

```js
function editar_lancamento(id)
{
metodo_salvar = 'update';
$('#form')[0].reset(); // Redefinir o formulário em modals
$('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // Apagar class de erro
$('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string

//Ajax - Carregar dados do ajax
$.ajax({
    url : "lancamento/lancamento_obter_por_id/" + id,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function( tbl_lancamento )
    {
        $('[name="id"]').val(tbl_lancamento.id);
  $('[name="txt_tipo"]').val(tbl_lancamento.tipo);   
        $('[name="txt_descricao"]').val(tbl_lancamento.descricao);
  $('[name="txt_valor"]').val(tbl_lancamento.valor);
  $('[name="txt_dt_vencimento"]').val(tbl_lancamento.dt_vencimento);   
  $('[name="sel_categoria"]').val(tbl_lancamento.id_categoria);
  $('[name="sel_conta"]').val(tbl_lancamento.id_conta);
  $('[name="txt_recebido"]').val(tbl_lancamento.recebido);
  $('[name="txt_dt_pagamento"]').val(tbl_lancamento.dt_pagamento);
  $('[name="sel_forma_pagamento"]').val(tbl_lancamento.forma_pagamento);   
 
  var tipo = $('#tipo').val();
  if(tipo == '1'){
   console.log(tipo);
   $('#modal_lancamento').modal('show'); // Abrir bootstrap modal quando completo carregado
      $('.modal-title').html('<i class="fa fa-plus "></i> Editar Receita'); //Definir título e icone para o título modal Bootstrap
   $(".modal-header").css('background-color', '#00A65A');
   $('#lbl_recebido').text('Recebido ?');
  } else {  
   console.log(tipo);
   $('#modal_lancamento').modal('show'); // Abrir bootstrap modal quando completo carregado
      $('.modal-title').html('<i class="fa fa-plus "></i> Editar Despesa'); //Definir título e icone para o título modal Bootstrap
   $(".modal-header").css('background-color', '#E9573F');
   $("#lbl_recebido").text('Pago ?');
  }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert('Erro para obter dados ajax');
  console.log('Erro para obter dados ajax') ;
  
    }
});
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara, ja oviu falar na bilbioteca moment.js? (https://momentjs.com/), ela pode ser uma solução paleativa para seu problema, alem de facilitar a manipulação de datas voce pode exibir ela em diversos formatos um deles sendo o padrao que voce deseja. 
moment().format('L');    // 07/06/2017

Comment: Certo, mas e sem o moment.js, tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: `var dateStr = '2017/06/07';`
`var dateSplit = dateStr.split("/");`
`var dateFormated = dateSplit[2] + "/" + dateSplit[1] + "/" + dateSplit[0];`
`console.log(dateFormated);`

Comment: @MeAjudaSilvio, funcionou!!!
Coloque como resposta que avalio!

Obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
//exemplo: tbl_lancamento.dt_vencimento.split('-').reverse().join("/"); 
var brDate = '2017-06-08'.split('-').reverse().join("/");
console.log(brDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma possibilidade mais braçal seria esta:

```
var dateStr = '2017/06/07'; 
var dateSplit = dateStr.split("/");
var dateFormated = dateSplit[2] + "/" + dateSplit[1] + "/" + dateSplit[0]; 
console.log(dateFormated);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa alterar o formato da data, existem diversas maneiras de fazer, segue abaixo um exemplo simples.

Mude isso :

```
 $('[name="txt_dt_vencimento"]').val(tbl_lancamento.dt_vencimento);
```

para :

```
 var spDate = tbl_lancamento.dt_vencimento.split('-');
 $('[name="txt_dt_vencimento"]').val(spDate[2]+'/'spDate[1]+'/'+spDate[0]);
```

Comment: veja erro `Uncaught ReferenceError: editar_lancamento is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (lancamento:1)`

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido com a resposta do MeAjudaSilvio

```js
var dateStr = tbl_lancamento.dt_vencimento;
var dateSplit = dateStr.split("-");
var dateFormated = dateSplit[2] + "/" + dateSplit[1] + "/" + dateSplit[0];
console.log(dateFormated);
$('[name="txt_dt_vencimento"]').val(dateFormated);
```