# Exibir campo data padrao BR aaaammdd para dd/mm/aaaa com javascript

Tags: javascript, html, data

olá
eu tenho um campo que recebe automaticamente uma data de um outro sistema, mas ele me manda em padrao americano, gostaria de exibir na tela com o padrao dd/mm/aaaa;

```html
 <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="proximoVenc">Data Ultimo Vencimento</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="proximoVenc" id="proximoVenc" value="20181105">
          </div>
```

Comment: Podes explicar melhor _"recebe automaticamente uma data de um outro sistema"_?

Comment: [Esse link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/211246/5043) tem o que você precisa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes tratar isso como uma string, ou converter para Date e mostrar com as regras do país.

tratando como string:

```js
var formatoBr = '2020/05/10'.split('/').reverse().join('/');
console.log(formatoBr); // 10/05/2020
```

Para converter e tratar como Date podes fazer assim:

```js
var [ano, mes, dia] = '2020/05/10'.split('/').map(Number);
var date = new Date(ano, mes - 1, dia);
var formatoBr = date.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR');
console.log(formatoBr); // 10/05/2020

// ou ainda:
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR', {
  weekday: 'long',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric'
})); // domingo, 10 de maio de 2020
```

Se tiveres sempre 8 dígitos sem separadores como indicaste agora na pergunta podes fazer de *N* maneiras diferentes... uma sugestão pode ser:

```js
var formatoUS = '20200510';
var [ano, mes, dia] = formatoUS.match(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/).slice(1);
var formatoBr = [dia, mes, ano].join('/');
console.log(formatoBr); // 10/05/2020
```

Podes também usar o `type="date"` no `input`, mas nesse caso há mais limitações à formatação, pois confias ao browser a tarefa da formação.

Comment: me desculpe, mas na verdade eu recebo a data sem "/" chega pra mim 20181105 e preciso que aparece 11/05/2018

Comment: @Rapha essa mudança na pergunta é muito importante e torna a minha resposta errada... Tens sempre 8 dígitos na data? ou há casos em que o mês ou a data tenham somente 1 dígito?

Comment: Sempre 8 digitos

Comment: @Rapha juntei uma sugestão para essa variante.

Answer (score 3):

Usando JavaScript puro, você pode usar [a resposta do Sérgio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/298112/112052), porém usando [substring](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) ao invés de `split`:

```js
var str = '20181105';
var ano = Number(str.substring(0, 4));
var mes = Number(str.substring(4, 6));
var dia = Number(str.substring(6));
var output = new Date(ano, mes - 1, dia).toLocaleDateString('pt-BR');
console.log(output);
```

Repare que [precisei subtrair 1 do mês](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/405994/112052), pois os meses são indexados em zero (janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc).

*Outro detalhe é que `toLocaleDateString` pode não dar exatamente o formato "dd/mm/yyyy", dependendo do locale utilizado e das configurações do ambiente, conforme explicado na [parte final desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/408649/112052).*

---

### Moment.js

Mas se você puder usar uma biblioteca externa, eu recomendo o [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). Com ela, é bem mais fácil:

```js
var output = moment('20181105', 'YYYYMMDD').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

A primeira parte (`moment('20181105', 'YYYYMMDD')`) faz o *parsing* da data (`YYYYMMDD` indica que é ano, mês e dia), e depois o `format` gera uma string de acordo com o formato passado (`DD/MM/YYYY` -> "dia/mês/ano"). [Veja a documentação](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) para mais detalhes.